# No me funciona el código correctamente

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código en Js. La idea es que hay un input para introducir un nombre, y cada vez que se le haga click al botón de añadir, ese nombre se agregue a una lista para posteriormente mostrarla. Algo bastante sencillo.
El problema es el siguiente. Si hago un console.log() dentro de la función funciona, (o sea se ve que añade), pero si lo pongo fuera no.

Es decir. **Así NO FUNCIONA.**

```
let listaNombres = []
const nombres = document.querySelector(".nombres");
const btnAniadir = document.querySelector(".añadir");

cargarEventListeners();
function cargarEventListeners() {
    btnAniadir.addEventListener("click", agregarArray);
}

function agregarArray(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let nombre = nombres.value
    console.log(nombre)

    let lista = document.querySelector("#lista-nombres");
    lista.innerHTML += "<li>" + nombres.value + "</li>";
    listaNombres.push(nombre)
    nombres.value = "";

}

console.log(listaNombres.length)
   for (let nombre of listaNombres) {
    console.log(nombre)
   }
```

Sin embargo, **así SI FUNCIONA**

```
let listaNombres = []
const nombres = document.querySelector(".nombres");
const btnAniadir = document.querySelector(".añadir");

cargarEventListeners();
function cargarEventListeners() {
    btnAniadir.addEventListener("click", agregarArray);
}

function agregarArray(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let nombre = nombres.value
    console.log(nombre)

    let lista = document.querySelector("#lista-nombres");
    lista.innerHTML += "<li>" + nombres.value + "</li>";
    listaNombres.push(nombre)
    nombres.value = "";
    //si meto el console y for dentro del evento, veo que sí funciona

    console.log(listaNombres.length)
    for (let nombre of listaNombres) {
        console.log(nombre)
    }
}
```

No se, es que lo veo surrealista. Si la lista está declarada fuera, y cada vez que haga click se añade un elemento, ¿por qué luego no puedo visualizarla? O sea, si añado el elemento cada vez que hago click, ¿por qué si me recorro la lista desde fuera no puedo verla, pero desde dentro veo que sí que se ha añadido el elemento?

Comment: Porque el código solo se ejecuta una vez, luego se ejecuta la función si se hace `click`, pero no pasa por el `console.log` externo...

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en el primer caso apenas se carga el script se ejecuta inmediatamente esta línea:

```
console.log(listaNombres.length)
for (let nombre of listaNombres) {
  console.log(nombre)
}
```

en este momento `listaNombres` no tiene elementos, por lo que tiene length = 0 y el for no es recorrido, y estas líneas no se van a volver a ejecutar a no ser que recargues la pagina, lo que tambien te borrara `listaNombres` y te volverá a mostrar `length=0` y así sucesivamente.

En el segundo caso el `console.log()` está dentro de una función asociada a un evento, por lo que puede ejecutarse en cualquier momento y nos mostrara el valor actualizado de `listaNombres`. Lo que ocurre es totalmente lógico, el primer caso console.log() se ejecuta una vez y al principio (cuando no se agrego nada), en el segundo, se ejecuta en cada evento `'click'`, actualizando listaNombre e imprimiendo todos sus valores.

Aunque no estes imprimiendo los datos correctamente en el primer caso, el array listaNombres si se está llenando, solo que no lo muestras correctamente.

Comment: cuál es la solución? ¿hacer que se ejecute cuando se cargue el DOM?

Comment: @jucasmarcastilla no, te estoy mostrando porque funciona en el segundo caso y porque no en el primero, que se ejecute cuando cargue el DOM no va a cambiar nada, lo que tenes que hacer es ejecutar el console.log() dentro del callback agregarArray(e)

Comment: Y con el bucle? Si se inserta correctamente, ¿por no se muestra fuera del ámbito de la función?

Comment: porque nombreArrays no tiene nada en el momento de imprimirlo. El for se esta ejecutando, pero no tiene nada cuando se imprime. en cambio si lo pones dentro de agregarArray ya tiene valores insertados. No tiene nada que ver que el for este bien o no.

Comment: Entiendo entiendo. ¿Y que puedo hacer para imprimirlo fuera del ámbito?

Comment: Te referis fuera del ambito del cargarEventListener? para que queres hacer eso? si hay un momento ideoneo para imprimir el resultado, es justo despues de que cambie, osea poniendo console.lo() al final del event listener.